# Clojure newbie - Rewriting Java code to Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have some simple working java code which uses SMACK xmmp library which responds to incoming messages and accepts multiuser chat invitations. I am trying to convert this clojure. the bot logs in but doesn't respond to messages.

```
public class bot {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Starting session...");
    try {
        String server = "chat.hipchat.com";         
        XMPPConnection con = new XMPPConnection(server);
        con.connect();
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        con.login(username, password,"bot");
        System.out.println("Connected");

        ChatManager chatManager = con.getChatManager();
        final MyMessageListener messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

        ChatManagerListener  chatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListener() {
            public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
                chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
            }
        };
        chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);


        MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(con, new InvitationListener() {

            public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection con,
                    String room, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4,
                    Message arg5) {

                MultiUserChat muc2 = new MultiUserChat(con, room);
                  try {
                    muc2.join("Bot");
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // Thread.currentThread();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        // Disconnect from the server
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Ended session...");
}
}

public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getBody());
    try {
        chat.sendMessage("Smack> Message sent via API.");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}


(ns mybot.core
(:import [org.jivesoftware.smack
        Chat ChatManager MessageListener ChatManagerListener XMPPConnection XMPPException]
       [org.jivesoftware.smack.packet
        Message Presence]
       [org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc InvitationListener MultiUserChat] ))

(def con (XMPPConnection. "chat.hipchat.com"))


(defrecord MyMessageListener []
   MessageListener
   (processMessage [this chat message] ( println "Received Message" )))


 (def myMessageListner ( MyMessageListener. ))



 (defn add-chatManagerListener
  [connection]
  (println "Adding a chat manager lister")
  (.addChatListener (.getChatManager connection)
                (proxy [ChatManagerListener] []
                  (chatCreated [chat locally]
                    (.addMessageListner chat myMessageListner )
                    )
                  )))




(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Starting bot")
  (.connect con)
  (.login con "username" "pwd" "bot")
 (println (.isAuthenticated con))
 (add-chatManagerListener con))
```

Comment: What do you mean by " the bot logs in but doesn't respond to messages" ?

Comment: Does MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener do something important?  I don't see that in the clojure code

Comment: @G_A  MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener is the listner which accepts chat room invitations. I havent added that in clojure code since i couldnt get the one to one listner itself working

Comment: @Chiron (println (.isAuthenticated con)) prints true but the bot itself is not responding to messages. I mean nothing gets printed when i send a msg where as i am expecting "Received Message" to be printed

Comment: I noticed that the Java code sleeps for 10 seconds before terminating. The Clojure version exists immediately.

Comment: @ez121sl yes but i think that doesn't make any difference. I have added (Thread/sleep 10000) but didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not using `(def ...)` to maintain global state if you don't need to. This always kind of backfires. But maybe it's some kind of personal taste.

Records in Clojure are used as beans and I am pretty sure you can't use then to implement methods on interfaces. The definition is: `(defrecord name [& fields] & opts+specs)` where `fields` is a list of field names, not method names.

To instantiate Java interfaces or Clojure protocols you should use `reify`. The `proxy` macro should be used to extend abstract classes or override functions on classes. But `MessageListener` and `ChatManagerListener` are only interface, so from my point of view `reify` should be first choice.

I attached my version of your source, but I wasn't able to test is properly, so handle with care.

```lisp
 (ns mybot.core
   (:import [org.jivesoftware.smack
        Chat ChatManager MessageListener ChatManagerListener XMPPConnection XMPPException]
        [org.jivesoftware.smack.packet
         Message Presence]
        [org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc InvitationListener MultiUserChat] ))

 (defn connect [host username password]
   (doto (XMPPConnection. "chat.hipchat.com")
    (.login username password "bot")))

 (defn add-listener [connection callback]
   (let [chat-manager (.getChatManager connection)
         message-listener (reify
           MessageListener
             (processMessage [_ chat message] (callback chat message))
           )
         chat-listener (reify 
           ChatManagerListener 
             (chatCreated [_ chat _]
               (.addMessageListner chat message-listener)))
     ]
      (.addChatListener chat-manager chat-listener)      
      connection
   ))

 (def -main [& args]
   (let [con (connect "chat.hipchat.com" "username" "pwd")]
     (println (.isAuthenticated con))
     (add-listener con (fn [_ message] (println "Received Message:" message)))

      (Thread/sleep 10000)))
```

A common Clojure pattern is to pass callback functions as listeners, which I did for the `add-listener` function. This provides nice decoupling and hides away all the nasty OO stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Although not what you're asking for, I'd recommend using a library for this.

A shameless plug, there is clj-xmpp, of which I've done a fork
https://github.com/slipset/xmpp-clj/ which probably meets your needs.